# Jquery files are conflicting?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in using the Jquery files in head tag, as I am using the following .js files for both the android(mobile) and pc users. There is a .js file which is required for mobile (touch) related events , so What should I do? My sequence of .js files are as;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/topnav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-impromptu.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by conflicting?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: The application generates excpceptions whenever I include the last script file and running on pc. e.g
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Where is the conflict? Any errors in the console? Where is the touch events js file? Does that cause the conflict?

Comment: @Bilallilla please, provide this message errors in the description of your question.

Comment: Sound's pretty straight-forward to me. If it is a mobile browser, don't include the 4th script tag. That is best done using server-side code, such as php asp or coldfusion.

Comment: This is the exception "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: I am using asp.net,  so would you please provide me the asp.net code to add .js file at runtime and on the particular sequence[because in JQuery it is very critical].

Comment: Can you modify your question to point to what your real question is and add a tag for asp? What you are actually looking for is how to include code in asp based on the useragent. I'm sure there's already an answered question similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did alot of Research on it and atlost i found the solution.

I added there a server tag and it works .

```
<% if (Global.SystemType == SystemTypeEnum.Android) {%> <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <% }%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
    document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-impromptu.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
}
else{
    document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
}
```

Comment: I added there a server tag and it works .
<% if (Global.SystemType == SystemTypeEnum.Android)
       {%>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <% }%>